# How to make an ajax call in an express view

Tags: jquery, ajax, express

Is this AJAX code valid? I want the view to keep calling the same page so that if a user uploads a picture it simply appears to everybody on that page rather than having to refresh every now and then. I'm new to AJAX and still figuring it out. The picture do appear but not like I want them to. They're not getting styled by my css.

```
<script>
        $(function(){
            $.ajax({ url: 'http://localhost:3000/board'
                , type: 'GET'
                , dataType: 'html'
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                <% print.forEach(function(posts){ %> 
                    $('html').append('<div class="post-container">');
                        $('html').append('<h2> <%= posts.Title %> </h2>');
                        $('html').append('<hr>');
                        $('html').append('<a target="_blank" href=<%= "/viewer?id=" + posts.ID %>><img class="post-img" src=<%= "uploaded/" + posts.Img_path %>></a>');
                    $('html').append('</div>');
                <% }); %>
            })
            .fail(function() {
                console.log("Something went wrong!");
            });
        });

    </script>
```

And this is the route:

```
router.get('/board', function(req, res){
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM posts, function(err, result){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }else{
            res.render('board', {print: result});
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try with following `.done()` handler:

```
.done(function(data) {
    <% print.forEach(function(posts){ %> 
        $('html').append('<div class="post-container">'+
                '<h2> <%= posts.Title %> </h2>'+
                '<hr>'+
                '<a target="_blank" href=<%= "/viewer?id=" + posts.ID %>><img class="post-img" src=<%= "uploaded/" + posts.Img_path %>></a>'+
                '</div>');
    <% }); %>
})
```

Otherwise your `ajax` call is fine.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks you good sir. But there's another problem. I opened the page on two tabs. When a picture is uploaded on one of the tabs it should appear on the other but that's not what's happening. I have to refresh. This way the AJAX code has no use. So what can i do?

Comment: Thanks. I am not that much familiar with node.js and express but in this particular scenario; you will have to make `ajax` call after each few seconds lets say 20 seconds or so. Due to frequent `GET` call; newest data will be available on you page.